# Value of debug watch not shown immediately in PhpStorm

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm, watch

When I add element to the Debugger Watch in PhpStorm (using the Watches panel, not the Variables one) I can only see the var name but not the value. State change of "show value addresses" or adding the watch a second time shows me the values and let me inspect it but next time I use the debugger I need to do this steps again. I also tried checking the "show values inline" setting but still no success.

How can I configure my watch window to show watch values on switching to the windows without doing something else? (this worked when I installed PhpStorm and I have no idea what I have changed to affect this)

Snip of my debug value only showing var names:

[image: debug watch]

Comment: 1) Would be great if you record some screencast where you can show how it all works when you trying to debug some very basic script 2) maybe try resetting the layout (option under "cog" icon) 3) *"I also tried checking the "show values inline" setting but still no success."* This is different -- in shows current values directly in the editor -- https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2015/03/inline-debugging-for-php-in-phpstorm-9-eap/

Comment: Thx for your reply @LazyOne.
I'll create a screencast when i got time. At the moment i don't have a program installed for a cast and i need to check whats best first.
Resetting the layout did not do the job for me. The inline debug watch (from your link) is already working but still not the expandable watch in Debug window below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow separating the watches window from the variables window did the trick for me - values are shown immediatly then. When i merge them in one window so i can tab between them it doesn't work. Not really what i wanted but i can work with this.